# how to get flat value from muitiple values_list? Django database

Tags: django, django-templates, django-database

I am getting postgresql data from my server and fill out the table down below.
I was able to join 3 different tables and get columns I want from them.

However, it gives me none-formatted object. Is there any way I can fill out the table using joined query one by one..?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MffOQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhcps.png)

views.py

```
 vlan_query_results = Vlans.objects.select_related('vlan_id').values_list('name', 'gateways__vip', 'gateways__backup', 'gateways__master', 'gateways__nat', 'gateways__vhid', 'subnets__dhcp', 'subnets__dns').order_by('vlan_id')
```

template

```
 {% for object in vlan_query_results %}
    <tr  #id='items-table'>
      <th scope="row" class="checkbox-row"><input type="checkbox" name="item" /></th>
        <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>


     <td class="item"> {{object }}</td>
 <td class="item"> </td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead using `values_list`, you should use DRF Serializers to get the response in a dictionary like structure with only the fields you want.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class VlansSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gateways_vip = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='gateways__vip')
    gateways_backup = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='gateways__backup')
    gateways_master = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='gateways__master')
    gateways_nat = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='gateways__nat')
    gateways_vhid = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='gateways__vhid')
    subnets_dhcp = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='subnets__dhcp')
    subnets_dns = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='subnets__dns')

    class Meta:
    model = Vlans
    fields = ('name', 'gateways_vip', 'gateways_backup', 'gateways_master', 'gateways_nat', 'gateways_vhid', 'subnets_dhcp', 'subnets_dns')
```

In your views.py:
`vlan_query_results = VlansSerializer(Vlans.objects.all(), many=True).data`

In your html:

```
{% for object in vlan_query_results %}
<tr>
  <th scope="row" class="checkbox-row">
     <input type="checkbox" name="item" />
  </th>
  <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
  <td class="item">{{object.name}}</td>
  <td class="item">{{object.gateways_vip}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You have to add the rest of the `<td></td>` tags in a similar manner.
Also, you cant add the `#id='items-table'` to the `<tr>` since it is in a loop and ids are supposed to be unique in a html page.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will try and let you know!